# can't upload images from website to my database using XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp

I am having some trouble uploading images to my blog, every time I try summiting the form it returns 'Failed to upload image :'. I can’t figure out the problem

```
    if (!empty($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
        $image_name = time() . '_' . $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $destination = ROOT_PATH . "/assets/images/" . $image_name;

       $result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $destination);

      if ($result) {
            $_POST['image'] = $image_name;
            
        }else {
            array_push($errors, 'Failed to upload image :');
            
        }
        
        
    }else {
        array_push($errors, 'Image is required!');
    }
```

Comment: Your destination path could be invalid - did you double check the path is valid and writeable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback
When using mac insure that the destination folder has read and writing permissions for other users.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If move_uploaded_file $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] is not a valid upload file, then no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file() will return false.

If $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] is a valid upload file, but cannot be moved for some reason, no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file() will return false. Additionally, a warning will be issued.

Make sure that the file is not empty.

Second: make sure the file name in English characters, numbers and (_-.) symbols, For more protection.

Third: Maybe the file is too big. Check the file size and also check php.ini for max_upload_size. Also check $_FILES["image"]["error"] to see what is the real error.

Comment: Failed to upload image :0
This is what I'm getting when I used the  $_FILES["image"]["error"]